# Hotchocolate get current instance id in resolver

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a domain entity Poll:

```
public class Poll
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add a new resolver to the Poll called "userHasAnswered" that is whether the logged in user has already taken a given poll. I've added a new field but I'm not sure how to access the current poll's Id in the resolver:

```
public class PollType : ObjectType<Poll>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Poll> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor
            .Field("userHasAnswered")
            .Resolve(context =>
            {
                var dataContext = context.Service<DataContext>();
                var userId = context.Service<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User.GetUserId();
                return dataContext.Answers.Any(x => x.UserId == userId && x.Question.PollId == /*How do if get the current pollId here?*/1);
            });
    }
}
```

Is this the ideal way of adding a new field that is dependant on the given poll's data or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your case is pretty common and hotchocolate's docs have a few words about it ([link](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v12/fetching-data/resolvers#accessing-parent-values)). So according to the article here's how you can get current poll ID in the resolver - `context.Parent<Poll>().Id`